# Can jQuery add something specific INSIDE an url?

Tags: jquery

I'm writing a multi-language site for a customer. URLs are all like:

mysite.com/audio/ecc...

mysite.com/video/ecc...

Now, I'd like to insert a link that point to translated versions of pages. I have a good result with:

```
$('myLink').click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('alt') == 'inglese') {
    window.location.href = '?lang=en';
  } else if ($(this).attr('alt') == 'italiano') {
    window.location.href = '?lang=it';
  }   
});
```

The result is something like

mysite.com/audio/?lang=en
mysite.com/video/?lang=en

But I'd like to generate url's placing the language pointer BEFORE page identifier, like:

mysite.com/**en**/video/ecc... 
mysite.com/**it**/audio/ecc...

Is ther a way to do that with jQuery / js?

Thank you for helping,

Marco

Comment: What the point to do it in JS ?

Comment: Sure, use split() or regexp.

Comment: Thank you, I'm gonna try now ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to do this via JS then try ..

```
var lang = '/en/';
'mysite.com/audio/ecc'.replace(/\//, lang);
```

Comment: So `window.location.href.replace(/\.com\//, '.com'+lang)`

Comment: Thank you very much! It perfectly works!  Anyway, why you asked me 'if you really need to do this via JS'? I'm not a pro, so I'd like to learn something new! ;)

Comment: I googled a little bit, maybe with php and a cookie?

Comment: Yes with the help of a cookie beeing processed inside your controller and then stored to session or something